# Is it possible to use Google Sign-in with Firebase Auth with third party cookies disabled?

Tags: firebase, cookies, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

The aim is to have a Google Sign-in button that works with Firebase Auth with third party cookies disabled.

The discussion here suggests using gapi.auth2:
[Use Google Firebase Authentication without 3rd Party Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757757/use-google-firebase-authentication-without-3rd-party-cookies)

However, gapi.auth2 also requires third party cookies: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/260

How do I get a Google Sign-in button to work with Firebase Auth and third party cookies disabled? If impossible, what are the alternatives?